# How can I have a loop run until I have a select number of results?

Tags: php

IN PHP: I have a for loop running through an array and if the value of each key does not match the value I'm looking for, I skip it.

How can I create a loop that runs until I have found 20 of the values that I am looking for.  So I can't have it be `for($i=0;$i<50;$i++)` because of the first 50, there may be only 2 values that match.  So it needs to run until 20 match.

UPDATE: I also need to iterate through the array, so I still need to check every value like this: $news_posts[$i]['category'];  if category is what i'm looking for then that's 1.  If its not, then I skip it.  I need 20.

Comment: Use a while(true) loop and break when your counter condition is met?

Answer (score 4):

You can use more than one condition:

```
for ($i=0, $found=0; $i<count($news_posts) && $found<20; ++$i)
{
    if ($news_posts[$i]['category'] == 'something')
    {
        ++$found;
        // do the rest of your stuff
    }
}
```

This will loop through everything in `$news_posts`, but stop earlier if 20 are found.

A for loop has three parts `(initialization; condition; increment)`. You can have multiple statements (or none) in any of them. For example, `for (;;)` is equivalent to `while (true)`.

Comment: +1 very rare with developers  to see `for` with more than 3 arguments

Comment: To be honest, this is the coolest thing i've seen thus far.  I did not know you could create this kind of for loop... it also solved my problem. 2 days in a row you've come to my help!!! Can we be best friends?

Comment: It's just a matter of recognizing patterns, something you get used to after doing this for a while. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$foundValues = 0;

while($foundValues < 20)
{
   //Do your magic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work.  Just be careful, if your count never gets higher than 19, the loop will run forever.

```
$count = 0;
while ($count < 20) 
{
    if (whatever)
    {
        $count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 0;
while(true){
if($count>20)
    break;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 0;
$RESULT_COUNT = 20;
while($count < $RESULT_COUNT) {
    // your code to determine if result is found

    if($resultFound) {
        $count++;
    }

    if($resultsEnd) { // check here to see if you have any more values to search through
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work and makes sure you don't end up in an infinite loop or try to access an index in an array that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Simply break out of the loop when some condition is true.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $countValue; $i++)
{
   //do something

   if ($i == 10) break;
}
```